# How to get full width of table html in smart phone browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

sorry for my poor English.

I'm creating horizontal scrollable table in HTML.

I wanto to get full width of table including out of viewing of browser to be worked sticky cell.

I tried to do this code with PC browser in jQuery.

```
jQuery(function() {
   var tableFullWidth = jQuery('.tableClass').width();
});
```

I could get it with it with PC.

However, I couldn't get full width of table in smartphone browser.

Maybe I thought it was not rendered full width of table only in smartphone browser - Chrome, Safari.

The width was always returned as smart phone width(Approximately 350px in my iphone6).

Could anyone please tell me how to get full width of table in smart phone browser?

-HTML

```
<div class="table-scroll">
<table class="data"> 
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td>Name2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Address1</td>
    <td>Addresse2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Age1</td>
    <td>Age2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

-CSS

```
.table-scroll{
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch
}

.table-scroll table.data{
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table.data tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1){
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

-jQuery

```
jQuery(function() {
  var width = jQuery('table.data').width();
  $('table.data').css('min-width',width + 'px');
});
```

My desired work with PC browser

https://gyazo.com/6700b686c9729dd0f1e726cd7712f69d

But this is working with smart phone browser

[image]

Comment: Plz add the display:block; for table class.. if it does'nt work, plz share the code

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this code..

**css**

```
table {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it doesn't work as I thought... I want horizontal scrollable table. I added my code please see it.